# How to compare two tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I need to check one table's column data is present in another table in same database using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining my table below.

> db_gallery:

```
id       subcat_id         image

1           60             123.png

2           60             234.png

3           58             456.png
```

> db_special_image

```
id      subcat_id         name        gallery_image

 1         60              aaa          123.png

 2         58              bbb          456.png
```

Here I need to check whether any gallery image is present inside the `db_special_image` table. I need to check with `subcat_id`. Suppose I know the `subcat_id=60`. I need to check any image from `db_gallery` table belongs to `subcat_id=60` is present in `db_special_image` table or not. If any image is there then it will return 1 otherwise 0. I need query for this. Please help me.

Comment: So you want list of images which are present in db_special_image or NOT present in db_special_image?

Comment: yes.I need query for that.

Comment: I am asking, are you comparing the image names Like if 123.png with subcatid 60 is present in both tables then your query should show that row as result. Correct?

Comment: @Hmmm : Yes,you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show images which are present in db_gallery as well as db_special_image...

**Bad Inner Query?**

```
SELECT * from db_gallery WHERE db_gallery.image IN (SELECT gallery_image FROM db_special_image WHERE db_gallery.subcat_id = db_special_image.subcat_id)
```

**Join**

```
SELECT * from db_gallery INNER JOIN db_special_image ON db_gallery.subcat_id = db_special_image.subcat_id AND db_gallery.image=db_special_image.gallery_image
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, can you please check and let me know if any issue

Comment: Ok,let me to test and let you know.

Comment: Welcome, poke if any other hurdles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mysql INNER JOIN` to JOIN two tables .
then use count('something'); `if it's !=0, echo "1"; else echo "0"`

[See this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql INNER JOIN`  The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables. `ON db_gallery.subcat_id = db_special_image.subcat_id`

```
SELECT name,db_gallery.subcat_id,image from db_gallery INNER JOIN db_special_image ON db_gallery.subcat_id = db_special_image.subcat_id
```

if num_rows count is more than 0 `echo "1";`

else `echo "0";`